# Background image not displaying in server

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, image

I'm trying to host an web application in server but the problem is when i run the application in **localhost** the background image is displaying but when i host it on **server** particularly background image is not at all loading please help regarding this

here is the code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<style>
body,h1 {font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif}
body, html {height: 100%}
.bgimg {
    background-image: url('~/img/smpl4.jpg');
    min-height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
</head>

<body class=" bgimg" >
</body>
</html>
```

how can i solve this ?

i'm able to get images from gridview button

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" style="margin-left:5px" runat="server" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/img/edit.png" Height="32px" Width="32px"/>
```

the images over here is perfectly loading its not able to load background image.

when i inspected the page its coming like this

**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: do u upload that image on server?

Comment: Is your folder structure the same?

Comment: @MandarSant  yes i have uploaded image to server

Comment: It's probably the path

Comment: @user6003859 yes folder structure is same

Comment: @Suhas because the path you are referring is not valid. try putting hard-coded path using DEv tools(press F12 and set path manually ) and check what happens? also, you can see if there is any error occured or  not in dev tools

Comment: @JeremyJackson i'm  geting other images properly but i have problem with background image only

Comment: @DirtyDeveloper its is able to load other images but its not loading background image in server

Comment: how you are accessing it in server? is it loading on client?? open  inetmgr-> find your website->right click->browse .. is that something you are performing???

Comment: There should be a mismatch in the src="whatever path". Local host sometimes excuses you because you might have not cleared cache and changed the path. On server check where your images are and try to add src="../file.extension"(repeat ../ until you reach your image backward from HTML) Make sure your extension is smaller in case because the server will punish you for sure if it is not smaller! esp Linux server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm using direct **url** of the image now its working fine it directly loads image through by **http url**

```
background-image: url('http://www.sample.com/sample/img/smpl4.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the root path operator `~` in client-side code, that is only available for code being run by .NET. `<ImageButton ImageUrl= "~/img/edit.png" />` works because it is being run server side.

Change to an absolute path, or a relative path without the root element. Something like `../img/smpl4.jpg`. Depending on your server setup you may also be able to access via `/img/smpl4.jpg`.

It sounds like you need to figure out what the correct URL should be, and get this to load by manually typing it into the browser. In Chrome, right click on one of your images (one that is displaying correctly), then click Inspect Element. In the chrome dev tools you will then see the full URL for your image. Use the working URL as an example for how to access your other image.

Comment: @Suhas I have updated the answer. The URLs I gave are just examples. Without seeing your folder structure or full URL there is no way I can guess what your relative path would be.

Comment: yeah i set the path **http://www.sample.net/sample/img/smpl4.jpg**  its working fine but my doubt is, is there any difference between  **/img/smpl4.jpg** because it loading from **server directory** and that's loading from **internet** does it effects security of the page i'm beginner please explain

Comment: Don't think I can offer any more advice unless you provide more information. We really need to know how you are accessing the site (like the url), and the directory structure of your website.

Answer (score 0):

To display the image on the server you should change the permission of the image to 755 after going to the directory in which image is present.

```
chmod -R 755 smpl4.jpg
```

Comment: where to change this permission

Comment: on the server go to the folder where the image is located through terminal and then execute the above command, if you're using a linux server.
And if on windows server just right click on the image and then change its permissions to read, write & execute.

Answer (score 0):

maybe check your filename (fontCase)? 
smpl4.jpg?
smpl4.JPG?

:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the extension of the image matches with the code. The uploaded image extension has to be smpl4.jpg not smpl4.JPG

This won't affect locally but on server side the image won't be visible. Check the extension of the image and change it to lower case as like on your code smpl4.jpg. Upload that image and check.

Answer (score 0):

{I CANNOT WRITE COMMENT So i have copied suhas response comment}

yeah i set the path sample.net/sample/img/smpl4.jpg its working fine but my doubt is, is there any difference between /img/smpl4.jpg because it loading from server directory and that's loading from internet does it effects security of the page i'm beginner please explain – Suhas

*Explanation:*

> Suhas you have set '~/' or '/' when you point to root directory. In your
>   case your root directory is 'sample.net' (probably). Suppose you set root directory to 'sample.net' then you can use '/sample/img/smpl4.jpg' (first slash(/) after colon (') consider path from root directory).

Answer (score 0):

or maybe is wrong path?
is it write in index.html like this?

```
workspace/    
workspace/img/smpl4.jpg    
workspace/css/style.css    
workspace/index.html
```

if in index.html

write `url('img/smpl4.jpg')`

if in style.css

write `url('../img/smpl4.jpg')`